# How do I derive the formula of frequency of a organ pipe when both ends are closed?

Tags: waves

How do I derive the formula of frequency of a organ pipe for a standing wave? When both ends are closed assume there are diaphragm at the end, which are producing the wave.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it the normal way as in a displacement wave at closed end there are nodes.

The result for this would be same as of imagining a pressure wave in both end open organ pipe.

Here's [a link](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/flutes.v.clarinets.html)! Where there is a animation of wave.
If we compare it the wave is same as of pressure wave of both end open for a both end closed displacement wave

Hence

$freq = \frac{n\nu}{2L}$

We can say that this symmetry is due to point of node and antinode in both pressure and displacement wave.
Further explanation in this image
[image]